# How to remove round corners from Apple Touch Icons for website

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, icons

Is there any way to remove the rounded corners that apple devices add to your website icon?

I used

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

Which acts effect and rounded corners

```
<link  rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

which doesn't add any effect, but still has rounded corners.

I found the above tutorial [here](http://botcrawl.com/how-to-setup-an-apple-touch-icon-for-your-website-and-individual-webpages/)

Is there any way to remove the rounded corners??

Comment: see this link , may be you can find something from this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: @Paras the only useful line i can find is "If you create an icon with a background that disappears when it's viewed on the Home screen, users don't see the rounded corners." what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the rounded corner effect. From the tutorial you linked to:

> By default Apple will round corners of the Apple Touch Icon. This rule applies for all options.

All icons on the home screen, whether they're from a web site or an app, get rounded corners. What you can do is turn off the gloss effect, which the tutorial you've linked to shows you how to do. Sorry!

Comment: what does this line mean "If you create an icon with a background that disappears when it's viewed on the Home screen, users don't see the rounded corners."? at link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: It's referring to old versions of iOS, where you couldn't change the desktop background and could make rounded corners 'disappear' by having an icon with a black background. This doesn't work anymore, because users can change their backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

See this link [IconsImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Read the whole Topic which Name is **App Icons** from this above link...

When iOS displays your app icon on the Home screen of a device, it automatically adds the following visual effects:

1. Rounded corners
2. Drop shadow
3. Reflective shine (unless you prevent the shine effect)

For example, a simple 57 x 57 pixel iPhone app icon might look like this:

[image]

When it’s displayed on an iPhone Home screen, iOS adds rounded corners, a drop shadow, and a reflected shine. So the same app icon would look like this:

[image]

Comment: i know that, I am just asking if there is a way to remove the rounded corners. I cannot find anything regarding removing the rounded corners in the article.

Comment: @Ankur see the topic Newsstand Icons , may be you can find out something from that but icon is create defult from ios center with these above threee effoct by default dude.. but i just try to give some tutorial about that so ,ay be this helpful to you so... read the Topic "Newsstand Icons" :)